# Checkstyle if statement rule

Tags: checkstyle

Is there any rule that I can use for restricting following `if` statements :

```
if ( null == name ) {
...
}
```

Basically, `null` should be always on the right side of statement e.g.

```
if ( name == null ) {
...
}
```

Comment: May I ask, why?

Comment: @PM77-1 because I believe that `name == null` is more human readable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sevntu has a custom check called `AvoidConstantAsFirstOperandInConditionCheck` which does what you want.

```
$ cat TestClass.java
public class TestClass {
    void method() {
if ( null == name ) {} // violation
if ( name == null ) {} // OK
    }
}

$ cat TestConfig.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <property name="charset" value="UTF-8"/>

    <module name="TreeWalker">
<module name="com.github.sevntu.checkstyle.checks.coding.AvoidConstantAsFirstOperandInConditionCheck" />
    </module>
</module>

$ java -jar checkstyle-8.9-sevntu-1.29.0-all.jar -c TestConfig.xml TestClass.java
Starting audit...
[ERROR] TestClass.java:3: Constant have to be second operand of '=='. [AvoidConstantAsFirstOperandInCondition]
Audit done.
Checkstyle ends with 1 errors.
```